# Change background color of selected item from current navigation with parameters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, css, sharepoint-on-prem

I wrote some classes in one of my SharePoint sites, that when you click on one of the links in the current navigation, the background color of the item changes to #eb8c00 :

**CSS CODE:**

```
#sideNavBox .ms-core-listMenu-selected:link,#sideNavBox .ms-core-listMenu-selected:visited,#sideNavBox .ms-core-listMenu-selected{
background-color: #eb8c00 !important;
color: #fff;
}
```

JS CODE:

```
unction OrderQL() {
     $( "#sideNavBox a.selected" ).each(function( ) {
       $(this).removeClass('selected');
     });

     /*set dynamic css logic*/
     $("#sideNavBox ul.root>li.static").css("border-bottom","1px solid #d6d6d6");
      $("#sideNavBox ul.root>li.static").css("border-top","1px solid #fff");

     if($('#sideNavBox .menu-item.selected').length){
      //propagates the selected class, up the three.
      $('li.static').removeClass('selected');
      $('#sideNavBox .menu-item.selected').parents('li.static').addClass('selected');
```

It's worked fine in all of my sites, but now i have a site that all of the links in the current navigation leads to the same view, with different parameters.

**Example of 2 link in the current navigation:**
/Mysite/myzone/TaxDepartment/DocLib/Forms/view5.aspx?Qatg=IAS
/Mysite/myzone/TaxDepartment/DocLib/Forms/view5.aspx?Qatg=DD

Because of that, the code treat all of the links as one, and it change the color of the last link no matter on which one i clicked.

I really appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an issue with SharePoint. Even if you remove the customisations you can see the last link is selected irrespective of which link you clicked.

Workaround is first fix the navigation element and then `addClass`

```
$("#sideNavBox .menu-item.selected").removeClass("selected");
var query = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop() + location.search
var link = $("a[href*='" + query + "']:first");
var table = $(link).parent().parent().parent().parent();
link.addClass("selected");
table.addClass ("selected");
```